# How to run mulitiple Django Python scripts from a single .py file in VS Code Terminal?

Tags: python, django, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal

Is there a possible way to start a Django project with a single Python script in the VS Code Terminal?

I need to call the following three scripts to run my project:

- `pipenv shell`
- `python manage.py runserver`
- `python manage.py sass-compiler --watch`

And I want them to be all called when I run a `start.py` script.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to do this in a single terminal window with something like tmux, or in three distinct terminals in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the current directory of your project, you run this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```